# const usage with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I am going over C and have a question regarding `const` usage with pointers.  I understand the following code:

```
const char *someArray
```

This is defining a pointer that points to types of char and the `const` modifier means that the values stored in `someArray` cannot be changed.  However, what does the following mean?

```
char * const array
```

Is this an alternate way of specifying a parameter that is a char pointer to an array named "array" that is `const` and cannot be modified?

Lastly, what does this combination mean:

```
const char * const s2
```

For reference, these are taken from the Deitel C programming book in Chapter 7 and all of these are used as parameters passed to functions.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`const char*` is, as you said, a pointer to a char, where you can't change the value of the char (at least not through the pointer (without casting the constness away)).

`char* const` is a pointer to a char, where you can change the char, but you can't make the pointer point to a different char.

`const char* const` is a constant pointer to a constant char, i.e. you can change neither where the pointer points nor the value of the pointee.

Comment: You've got no idea how many times I've checked this answer... LOL! Many thanks!

Comment: @kazbeel Easy rule to remember: `const` always makes const what is left to it, unless nothing is left to it, then it makes const what is right to it, since `const char *` and `char const *` are in fact the same expression. If left to it is an asterisk, it makes the pointer const but not the value, if left/right to it is a type, it makes the value itself const but not the pointer.

Answer (score 33):

From [what is the difference between const int*, const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const):

> Read it backwards...
>
> ```
> int* - pointer to int
> int const * - pointer to const int
> int * const - const pointer to int
> int const * const - const pointer to const int
> ```

Answer (score 14):

```
//pointer to a const
void f1()
{
    int i = 100;
    const int* pi = &i;
    //*pi = 200; <- won't compile
    pi++;
}

//const pointer
void f2()
{
    int i = 100;
    int* const pi = &i;
    *pi = 200;
    //pi++; <- won't compile
}

//const pointer to a const
void f3()
{
    int i = 100;
    const int* const pi = &i;
    //*pi = 200; <- won't compile
    //pi++; <- won't compile
```

}

Answer (score 10):

You should try out `cdecl`:

```
~ $ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain const char *someArray
declare someArray as pointer to const char
cdecl> explain char * const someArray
declare someArray as const pointer to char
cdecl> explain const char * const s2
declare s2 as const pointer to const char
cdecl>
```

Comment: Is this a Linux-only utility ?

Comment: I have never tried to use it otherwise, but I'm sure it's available for other operating systems, as part of cygwin or otherwise.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, I'll see if there's a Mac build or if it comes with XCode.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
char * const array;
```

It means that the pointer is constant. Also,

```
const * const char array;
```

means a constant pointer to constant memory.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating what other users wrote, but I want to provide context.

Take these two definitions:

```
void f1(char *ptr) {
    /* f1 can change the contents of the array named ptr;
     * and it can change what ptr points to */
}
void f2(char * const ptr) {
    /* f2 can change the contents of the array named ptr;
     * but it cannot change what ptr points to */
}
```

Making the pointer itself `const`, like in the f2 example, is <s>absolutely</s> almost pointless. Every parameter passed to a function is passed by value. If the function changes that value, it only changes its local copy and has no effect on the calling code.

```
/* ... calling code ... */
f1(buf);
f2(buf);
```

In either case, `buf` is unchanged after the function call.

---

Consider the strcpy() function

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

One possible implementation is

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src) {
    char *bk = dest;
    while (*src != '\0') {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = *src;
    return bk;
}
```

This implementation changes both `dest` and `src` inside the function only. Making either of the pointers (or both) `const` would gain nothing for the strcpy() function or to the calling code.

Comment: You have an error in the comment inside `f2`. "can" should be "can't"

Comment: @ManuelSelva ... try `void f2(char * const ptr) { ptr[1] = 'a'; }` and `char foo[] = "Hi"; f2(foo); puts(foo);` ... https://ideone.com/eHwOuW

Comment: You edited the code since yesterday, right ;-) ? Sorry for my comment, I read your code wrongly.

Comment: No worries @ManuelSelva. Thanks for paying attention and giving feedback!