# Invalid initializer when using gettext in a structure

Tags: c, struct, gettext, gtk3

I want to create a multiple array of my structure:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gi18n.h>

typedef struct  {
    gchar icon_name[24];
    int response;
    gchar label[10];
} button_data;

GtkWidget * create_button_helper (GtkDialog *dialog) {
    button_data b[3] = {
        { "dialog-ok", GTK_RESPONSE_YES, _("Yes")},
        { "dialog-close", GTK_RESPONSE_NO, _("No") },
        { "", 0 }
    };
    gint index;
    for (index = 0; b[index].response != 0; index++) {
        GtkWidget *tmp;
        GtkWidget *i;
        tmp = gtk_button_new_with_label (b[index].label);
        i = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name (b[index].icon_name, GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
        gtk_button_set_image (GTK_BUTTON (tmp), i);
        gtk_dialog_add_action_widget (GTK_DIALOG (dialog), tmp, b[index].response);
    }
}
```

But I get the error about invalid initializer, any helps?

When compiled with `gcc -Wall` the following relevant warnings are given:

```
./tmp.c: In function ‘create_button_helper’:
./tmp.c:12:9: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
         { "dialog-ok", GTK_RESPONSE_YES, _("Yes")},
         ^
./tmp.c:12:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘b[0].label’) [-Wmissing-braces]
./tmp.c:12:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
./tmp.c:12:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘b[0].label[0]’) [enabled by default]
./tmp.c:13:9: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         { "dialog-close", GTK_RESPONSE_NO, _("No") },
         ^
./tmp.c:13:9: warning: (near initialization for ‘b[1].label[0]’) [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Note: `{ "", 0 }` has 2 of the 3 elements listed.

Comment: Posting the error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `struct` definition to

```
typedef struct  {
    const gchar *icon_name;
    int response;
    const gchar *label;
} button_data;
```

be aware that the values of `icon_name` and `label` will not exists outside of the `create_button_helper`, but it seems you wont need them anywhere else.

Also initialize the array this way

```
button_data b[3] = {
    { "dialog-ok", GTK_RESPONSE_YES, _("Yes")  },
    { "dialog-close", GTK_RESPONSE_NO, _("No") },
    { NULL, 0, NULL }
};
```

and in the loop you can use

```
for (index = 0; b[index].icon_name != NULL; index++)
```

also, if you have a sentinel value you don't need to specify the size of the array (as the constructive comments from @chux mention add the `const` here) this would be better in fact

```
const button_data b[] = {
    { "dialog-ok", GTK_RESPONSE_YES, _("Yes")  },
    { "dialog-close", GTK_RESPONSE_NO, _("No") },
    { NULL, 0, NULL }
};
```

since now you can add more `button_data`s to your array, wihtout changing anything else.

Comment: Why the 2nd `const` in `const gchar *const icon_name;`?  Should not `const gchar *icon_name;` be sufficient?

Comment: It would be, however it is a good practice to mark everything `const` which is not meant to be changed. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446120/const-usage-with-pointers-in-c

Comment: Minor: Reassigning the pointer `const gchar *icon_name` would not be a problem.  @meskobalazs If the `button_data` was meant to be `const`, code should be `const button_data b[3] = ...`.

Comment: Nice use of sentinel.

Comment: `"dialog-ok"` is a `const char *`.  Does that convert directly to `const gchar *`?  Or does code need `_("dialog-ok")`?

Comment: Thanks iharob, your explanation helped... kudos for you ^_^

Comment: @chux No, `gchar` is just `typedef char gchar;` and `_(x)` macro expands to `gettext(x)` a gnu function for string translation.

Comment: Minor point:  Curious about `typedef char gchar`.  If that is _always_ true, why have a typedef and instead just use `char`?   Suppose that is an SO question.  If is not always true, then this solution may have a problem with `typedef something_else gchar`.

Comment: @chux You are right, and may be it's not true for other operating systems, but I can't be sure, because have I never worked on a cross platform `gtk+` app. It could actually be a SO question it think. I use Linux by the way, so by others a actually suspect of MS Windows, since they have a `TCHAR` which could be `char` or `wchar_t` so I suppose there it could be `typedef TCHAR gchar`. Although the fix would be to use the `TEXT()` macro, and one can perfeclty write one for compatibility like `#define TEXT(x) (x)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the reason, but it seems that the minimal change to your code to make it work would be to change the type of the `label` of the `struct` to a pointer instead of an array:

```
gchar *label;
```

This may be because the `_()` macro expands to something that returns a `gchar *`, but again I'm not sure.

---

Update: Just checked glib's source code:

In `glib/gi18n.h`, we have (excerpt):

```
#include <libintl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  _(String) gettext (String)
```

And in `libintl.h` we have (excerpt):

```
extern char *gettext (const char *__msgid)
     __THROW __attribute_format_arg__ (1);
```

So I guess this is why `char[]` doesn't work but `char *` does.

Comment: may be but don't post this as an answer, do it as a comment. And usually the `_(x)` macro expands to `gettext((x))` which returns `char *` so there should not be any problem with the `const` qualifier, the result of `gettext()` should not be modified in however, and it is actually a warning in it's manual page.

Comment: @iharob I get your `const gchar *` part but I don't get why the pointer has to be constant - that part can be modified without causing any problems.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
button_data b[3] = {
        { "dialog-ok", GTK_RESPONSE_YES, _("Yes")},
        { "dialog-close", GTK_RESPONSE_NO, _("No") },
        { "", 0 }
};
```

is bad, the first two init lists are 3 elements and the last one is 2, also to be syntactically correct

button_data b[3] would be button_data b[][3].

Although I suspect this is not what you are trying to achieve, you will want something more like this.

```
button_data b[3] = {
    some_button_data, some_button_data, some_button_data
}
```

Because button_data probably can't be initialized the way you are trying to do it with an array initialization list.

But I'm not really used to GTK 3 so I can't help you beyond this.