# Usage const modifier in function

Tags: c, constants

From the linux kernel scripts/mod/modpost.c:

```
static int is_vmlinux(const char *modname)
{
    const char *myname;

    myname = strrchr(modname, '/');
    if (myname)
            myname++;
    else
            myname = modname;

    return (strcmp(myname, "vmlinux") == 0) ||
           (strcmp(myname, "vmlinux.o") == 0);
}
```

How I understand:

This is defining the pointer to type of char and the const modifier. This pointer cannot be changed. But on the next lines we change the pointer.

Is it correct? Looks like no. :(

Why in this code use const? What doing here const? Can we write it without const?

Comment: Its a pointer to const char, not a const pointer to char.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446150/8513665

Comment: that why I always write `char const *modname`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [const usage with pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446120/const-usage-with-pointers-in-c)

Comment: In C, you read each variable declaration from right to left, and `*` as *"a pointer to"*. So, `const char *myname` is read as *"myname is a pointer to const char"*.  On the other hand, `char *const myname` is *"myname is a const pointer to char"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const char * myname;
```

is a pointer to constant (content). You are allowed to modify the pointer. e.g. `myname = NULL`, `myname++`, but modification of the content is *not* possible.

```
char * const myname;
```

is a constant pointer. The opposite is possible. You are **not** allowed to modify the pointer, but you *are* allowed to modify what it points to e.g. `*myname ^= ' '`, which makes letter upper case if it is lower case.