# Swift regards a C const pointer as mutable?

Tags: swift

I'm importing a C header in Swift using a bridging header. My C API looks something like this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
  char buff[80];
} MyStruct;

const char* GetBuff(const MyStruct* m);
```

Now in Swift I try to call it like this:

```
let b = MyStruct()
let mystr = String(cString: GetBuff(&b))
```

Then I get this compile error: "Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'b' is a 'let' constant". Why is this? The argument to GetBuff() is a const pointer. Isn't a const pointer immutable?

I know that changing 'b' to 'var b' will fix the problem but why is it necessary?

Comment: [`const char*` — is a `mutable` pointer to `const char`](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+char*x). Maybe you're looking for `char * const`, or `const char * const`?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446120/const-usage-with-pointers-in-c

Comment: @user28434: The `char *` return type is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let b` is a constant, therefore you cannot pass it as inout argument with `&b`. But you can use [`withUnsafePointer(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2431879-withunsafepointer) to obtain a (temporary) pointer to its value and pass that to the C function.

```
let b = MyStruct()
let mystr = withUnsafePointer(to: b) { String(cString: GetBuff($0)) }
```

Comment: Thanks! But why can't I pass its address? 'b' is a constant...

Comment: @bear_dk: `&b` in Swift is an “in-out-expression” to indicate that it can be modified in the function call. It cannot be used with `let` constants. Also constants in Swift do not necessarily have an address.