# How to pass argument in Swift to C function that takes an UnsafePointer?

Tags: swift, interop, unsafe-pointers

I've imported a C function called `geoToH3` that returns an `H3Index` (which is just a `UInt64`).

```
let h3Index = geoToH3(g: UnsafePointer<GeoCoord>!, r: Int32)
```

The function takes an `Int32` and a `GeoCoord` object, which is just an object with a pair of `Double`.

```
let geoCoord = GeoCoord(lat: 45.0, lon: -90.0)
```

How do I pass the `geoCoord` argument to this function since it takes an `UnsafePointer`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351981/swift-regards-a-c-const-pointer-as-mutable

Comment: @MartinR the `withUnsafePointer` generic function would return a type of `GeoCoord`, as far as I understand how it works, but the C function is expecting an argument of type `UnsafePointer<GeoCoord>`. Or can it return an unsafe pointer?

Comment: It should be `let h3Index = withUnsafePointer(to: geoCoord) { geoToH3($0, 5) }` similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60352083/1187415.

Comment: You can make this an answer as this answers my question perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`withUnsafePointer(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2431879-withunsafepointer) must be used here:

```
let h3Index = withUnsafePointer(to: geoCoord) {
     (pointer: UnsafePointer<GeoCoord>) -> H3Index in
     return geoToH3($0, 5)
}
```

or shorter (using shorthand parameter syntax and implicit return):

```
let h3Index = withUnsafePointer(to: geoCoord) { geoToH3($0, 5) }
```

- `withUnsafePointer(to:)` calls the closure with a pointer to the 
  `geoCoord` value.
- The C function is called with that pointer as the first argument.
- The return value from the C function is the return value of `withUnsafePointer(to:)` and assigned to `h3Index`.

It is important that the pointer is only valid during the execution of `withUnsafePointer(to:)` and must not be stored or returned for later use.

As an example, the following would be undefined behaviour:

```
let pointer = withUnsafePointer(to: geoCoord) { return $0 }
let h3Index = geoToH3(pointer, 5)
```

Comment: I have one more, just posted it, I hope you look at it... you are a god.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply call with a student ref there contain UnsafePointer name.

```
let stu = student(id: 1, name: input?.cString(using: .utf8), percentage: 10.0)
passByStudent(stu)
```

Try this example:

MyC.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeInput(int *output) {
    *output = 5;
}

typedef struct student Student ;

void passByStudent(Student stu);

struct student {
    int id;
    const char *name;
    float percentage;
};

void passByStudent(Student stu) {
    stu.id = 5;
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var output: CInt = 0
        changeInput(&output)
        print("output: \(output)")


        let input: String? = "strudent name"
        let stu = student(id: 1, name: input?.cString(using: .utf8), percentage: 10.0)
        passByStudent(stu)
    }
}
```

Follow this example step-by-step:

1. Create a Swift Project
2. Create MyC.c file and write code.

[image]

3. Click on your project.
4. Click the Build Setting Tab.
5. Select all tab
6. search with Objective-c Bridging Header
7. Double click Here.
8. After that left-click on MyC.c file, drag and drop inside popup layer.

[image]

9. You can define your function inside Practice-Bridging-Header.h

   void changeInput(int *output);

[image]

10. Write code inside your ViewController.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var output: CInt = 0
        changeInput(&output)
        print("output: \(output)")


        let input: String? = "strudent name"
        let stu = student(id: 1, name: input?.cString(using: .utf8), percentage: 10.0)
        passByStudent(stu)
    }
}
```