# Why is it possible to change the value of an integer indirectly via a pointer to a constant int?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, declaration

I read many old questions, many answers about `const` keyword in a declaration to deeply understand the syntax of declarations.

I played with `const` and I am now a little bit confused with this example :

```
int i;
i=1;
int const *ptr_i;
ptr_i=&i;
printf("%d\n",*ptr_i);
i=2;
printf("%d\n",*ptr_i);
```

If `int const *` is a pointer to a **constant integer**, why `ptr_i=&i;` is allowed ? `i` is not a constant integer.

Moreover, if the value of `i` is changed from 1 to 2 (obviously, it is possible because `i` is not a constant integer), the second `printf` displays 2. I am not surprised because the value of `i` has been changed and `ptr_i` is a pointer to `i`.

I, also checked that he value of ptr_i has not changed ( `printf("%p ",ptr_i)` ).

Where is my misunderstanding ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? The variable `i` isn't constant. You can modify it as you please. You can't however use the `ptr_i` to do that modification. So `*ptr_i = 5` is not allowed. This is very common for functions, where you pass a pointer to constant something to indicate that the function will not modify the data.

Comment: const is a way to give someone a pointer and say "_you_ are not allowed to modify it". It's not a way to declare that "_no one_ is allowed to modify this data".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446150/13547857. You can't change the pointed value through that pointer.

Comment: Thanks to all. It is very clear now. The value could not be changed through the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If `int const *` is a pointer to a **constant integer**,…

`int const *` is not a pointer to a constant integer. It is a pointer to an `int` for which the `int` type is qualified with `const`.

`const` is a misnomer. “Read only” is closer to an accurate description; it means that “with this type, the value will only be read.” Meaning that somebody else with a different pointer (same value, different type) can write to the object.

It is not purely read-only either. In C, if an object was defined without `const`, but you have a pointer to it of type `const int *`, you can convert the pointer to `int *` and use the new pointer to modify the object, and that is defined by the C standard. `const` was added to the language late, so it is somewhat grafted on rather than fully integrated, and it does not serve as a complete solution for preventing writes to objects. Mostly, it performs an **advisory** service: When a type is qualified with `const`, the compiler must warn you about attempts to use it directly to modify an object it points to. That helps programmers avoid bugs.

Comment: How can I convert a `int const *` pointer to a `int *` pointer ?

Comment: @Stef1611: Use a cast: `int *NewPointer = (int *) ptr_i;`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It needs another pointer declaration.

Comment: @Stef1611: No, you could use the converted pointer directly: `* (int *) ptr_i = 3;`.

Comment: It is the first time I see a cast on the left part of an affectation. Very funny.

Comment: "Meaning that somebody else with a different pointer (same value, different type) can write to the object." --> If that "different type" was a `float *`, would that venture into aliasing issues?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Sure, but not relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

> If `int const *` is a pointer to a constant integer, why `ptr_i=&i;` is
> allowed ? `i` is not a constant integer.

You decided that the object referenced by the `ptr_i` (in this case `i`) should not be changed using this pointer. But this pointer can reference a not `const` object.

It **DOES NOT** work the opposite way.

```
const int a = 5;
int *ptr = &a;

*ptr = 6;   // UB
```

In the snippet above `*ptr = 6;` invokes **Undefined Behavior** as you modify `const` qualified object.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it. I have a warning.